How to set timeout between requests to Telegram servers?
I need to set timeout before every send_messages function
await client([
    SendMessageRequest('me', 'Hello'),
    # need to 10 sec timeout
    SendMessageRequest('me', ', '),
    # need to 10 sec timeout
    SendMessageRequest('me', 'World'),
    # need to 10 sec timeout
    SendMessageRequest('me', '.')
], ordered=True)

Send request to telegram server every 10 seconds. I don't want to get ban ;(

Could be wrong here in case somebody wants to correct me but:
You can do:
messages = [
    SendMessageRequest('me', 'Hello'),
    SendMessageRequest('me', ', '),
    SendMessageRequest('me', 'World'),
    SendMessageRequest('me', '.')
]

and then
for message in messages:
    await client(message)
    await asyncio.sleep(10) # change this to whatever you want your delay as

in order to avoid flooding it with requests.

Here I am sending 4 requests. I don't want to use this approach because telegram allows you to send a single packet with any number of requests embedded in it, so I want to use parallel.

Running two or more things in parallel inherently means they run at exactly the same time. If you need them to run one after the order, and with a delay, you cannot run them in parallel. The server will process them as soon as they arrive, so you must delay when you send them.
